# Error when trying to read a JSON file using pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, twitter

I'm using python (pandas) to read a JSON file with raw tweets but i'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)

I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: HERE IS A SAMPLE OF THE JSON

> {"created_at":"Sat Nov 16 14:15:52 +0000 2019","id":1195707056365461505,"id_str":"1195707056365461505","text":"Any arsenal red members on here, dm me please...got a couple questions\ud83d\ude05\ud83e\udd14","source":"\u003ca href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":974846850,"id_str":"974846850","name":"Rico Rodrigo","screen_name":"DatGuyTy_online","location":"Brum","url":null,"description":"Aspiring Accountant x Arsenal enthusiast x Anime addict","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":647,"friends_count":901,"listed_count":9,"favourites_count":24989,"statuses_count":24628,"created_at":"Tue Nov 27 22:25:31 +0000 2012","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1071377159682514945/Np4nGX5m_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1071377159682514945/Np4nGX5m_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/974846850/1554183093","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1573913752057"}

This is the code i'm using to read the file:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import re 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import json 
import os

tweet_file = 'raw_data.json' 
tweets = pd.read_json(tweet_file, convert_dates=True, lines=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Can you provide the json? The issue is probably in the file, not in your code.

Comment: Duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240982/valueerror-when-using-pandas-read-json). Do ```tweets = pd.read_json(open(tweet_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8"), convert_dates=True, lines=True)```

Comment: I've added a sample of the JSON file in the main post. @FelipeFaria unfortunately that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with my own json file, trying it with pandas:

```bash
File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py:1133, in FrameParser._parse_no_numpy(self)
   1129 orient = self.orient
   1131 if orient == "columns":
   1132     self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1133         loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1134     )
   1135 elif orient == "split":
   1136     decoded = {
   1137         str(k): v
   1138         for k, v in loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float).items()
   1139     }

ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (1)
```

I then opened the file in VSCode as a json and checked line 2 column 914 and found that after that column, there was a tab instead of spaces.

To fix this, I regex replaced all tabs with four spaces:

[image]

*Side remark: I had a json with many hardcoded `\n` linebreaks and thought that I would have to drop them as well, but these hardcoded `\n` do not harm, you can keep them.*

You may find other red markers in the JSON view of VSCode or some other JSON editor. I also ran into a "JSONDecodeError" error, see both fixes in one go at [How can I fix the error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: ..." when loading a json file with json.load()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77760525/11154841).